# NotifyComplete & Abort Methods are not existing in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

This below code is working in wp8.0 but not working in wp8.1 Universal apps

```
public class AudioPlayer : IBackgroundTask
{
  protected override void OnCancel()
    {
        //Some Code
        NotifyComplete();
        Abort();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is your base class?

Comment: Question is edited see now

Answer (score 1):

`NotifyComplete()` and `Abort()` methods are present in `ScheduledTaskAgent` class which is used in Windows Phone Silverlight applications. Since you are using Windows Phone XAML APIs, you don't need to do any such thing. Simply implement the `Run` method and put your code in it.